# What grass types would be good for contrasting lawns in Central Europe?

Tags: lawn, grass, variety-selection

I've seen a lawn which was composed with different grass types, I'd like to achieve a similar effect. I have a couple of concerns, they should:

- grow slowly, at similar rate,
- have different colour/tint,
- have similar requirements

The number of grass types available is enormous and it seems quite hard and risky to pick two that would fit. Do you know any that would pass the requirements?

edit: I found a similar lawn online (not from Europe though), please have a look:

[image]

Comment: Any images, the location and/or information on this lawn you've seen?

Comment: @Bamboo I've added a photo of a similar lawn, does it help?

Comment: Well yes and no - it just looks like one lawn has been cut short and the other left longer, but its possible the longer one is different grass. What country is it, I mean where this picture's taken? In USA, they have different grasses because of different climate regions.

Comment: I think it's from the USA. I haven't found any other relevant picture unfortunately though.

Comment: Okay, so where did you see this lawn you're talking about, what country/town?

Comment: Germany, Frankfurt nach Oder suburbs (east of Germany).

Comment: I really need to see a picture - the trouble is, checking online, all you get is mixed grasses - which is just the average lawn, they usually contain 3 or 4 different types of grass all mixed together, so not what you're after at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line on the lawn (from the pic you provided) is the property line, and yes, those are different grasses. The one on the left appears to be St. Augustine grass, while the one on the right is almost pure Bermuda grass.

In Europe, you won't be growing either of these, but you can get the same effect, using different colors and textures off cool season lawn grass. Like using a wider bladed, lighter hued tall fescue, such as KY-31 (mowed a little higher for effect) to contrast against a well groomed perennial rye lawn, such as Blackcat II (with a very dark, narrow blade and dense habit). There are others you could try as well (some fine fescues contrast well, especially with tall fescues, because of the huge difference in blade width.

Just be aware of the growth habits of the species you choose. All lawn grasses tiller, and spread slowly that way (thus the shallow trench dividing the two types), but some grasses (eg Kentucky Bluegrass) spread quickly by stolon, and that will be counter-productive. Some new rye grasses do this also, and are advertised as 'self-repairing' or similar. Avoid those.